# how to find the "Answer type" and "questionType" in NLP

Tags: nlp

I need to find out the "answer type detection" from a question. Is there any open api, which will provide me answer type like

"Where should we go for coffee"
Here the answer type will be location

Comment: This is not an easy task. You must have training data (question, answer type) in order to extract features and train a classifier e.g. svm. Another approach is to use regular expressions, e.g. Where * go for * --> Location. You have to keep in mind that answer types are domain dependent.

Comment: Thanks, Can you also guide me how can I start with this?, building a classifier, or RNN or a rule based engine

Answer (score 1):

Build a large training set like this:

```
question1 type1
question2 type2
...
```

Then train a classifier using bag of word models of questions as features of each question and typei as label.

After training, your classifier will be able to predict the label (question type) of a new sample.

To learn how to build a classification model easily you can use sklearn as in [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

To build your training dataset, you can have questions and question types yourself or you can use existing dataset as in [here](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/QA/QC/)